# Вставить исходный код с Github в проект Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, github

На Github хранятся только исходные коды программы. Как правильно импортировать склонированный проект в Eclipse, чтобы получился нормальный Eclipse-проект и осталась связь с github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"На Github хранятся только исходные коды программы. Как правильно импортировать склонированный проект в Eclipse, чтобы получился нормальный Eclipse-проект и осталась связь с github?" - От второго предложения мозг сломал.

Если вы хотите скопировать существующий проект и внести туда свои изменения, то Вам нужно сделать форк этого проекта.
Если вы хотите использовать часть кода чужого проекта в своем, то Вам нужно перенести этот код вручную в свой проект.
Если вы лишь хотите вносить изменения в исходные коды программы, используя IDE Eclipse, а программа была написана с использованием другой IDE, вероятно структура проекта отличается, и Вам придется выполнить кое-какие изменения. Например, создать новый проект eclipse, скопировать в него содержимое репозитория имеющегося проекта, сделать так, чтобы Ваш новый проект заработал, и сделать комит Ваших изменений.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Просто создала новый проект и заменила исходники.